# How can I login with my account on my wife's computer?

Tags: support, user-accounts

- On her computer, my wife is permanently logged into her Google account.
- She never uses (or has used) SU.
- I want to fix stuff on her computer and access my SU account to ask questions.
- I always use my Google login to login to my SU account (well, I'm also permanently logged in to Google and all SE sites I use).

**How can I use my Google login to log into SU on her (Win 10) machine, without having to log her out of her Google account?**

- I tried just logging in with my Google user/pass, but then I still get redirected to Google, where it says 'SU is asking for permission' to log in *with her account*.
- I tried several variations of using my Google OpenID login under *Other login options*/*OpenID login*, as per the [answers to this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/how-do-i-figure-out-my-google-openid-url), but this gives me *No OpenID endpoint found*.

I would like to do this without SU/SE staff being involved. They have enough to do already ;-)

Comment: What happens when you say yes to 'SU is asking for permission'? There is nothing stopping you being logged on using multiple different google accounts at the same time in the same browser. I quite often have two different gmail accounts open at the same time (in different tabs).

Comment: Log into both Google accounts, when you do this, you will be asked which Google account you want to use.  The alternative to this is connect multiple OpenID accounts to your account, and use one of those, on your wife's machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log in to Google by going to the account button (your picture then "switch accounts" iirc) at the top of any Google page you should be able to login to a second account without logging out the first. Then when you log in to SU it should ask which account you want to log in with.

Alternatively you can use an alternative browser, if she uses Chrome then install Firefox or vice versa, or use the browser built in profile management features.

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you can also choose "New Incognito Window" in Chrome ( or Firefox ) and then log into google. It will always give you a login screen and you won't mess with any settings that your wife has set up.